# 3cx firewall error message when testing ports

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, pbx

i just deployed a 3CX pbx VM, once i try to run the firewall test i get this error message with all the ports that are tested:

"testing port 9000... full cone test failed (How to resolve?)"

this happens with all the ports needed from 9000 to 9400 and then from 10600 to 10900

i am very familiar with the app (i have the advanced certification) but not with google cloud. is there a way to modify the firewall / nat that is providing access to this virtual machine?

Comment: Would you mind sharing how did you deploy this VM to Google Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the Cloud SDK command `gcloud`, you can create the firewall rule ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/firewall-rules/create)):

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create Allow-PBX-Rule --allow tcp:9000-9400,tcp:10600-10900
```

Otherwise, log in to the Google Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/

[document link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls)

- Click the Hamburger icon (top left)
- Go to Networking -> VPC Network -> Firewall rules
- Click the "Create Firewall Rule" button near the top.
- Complete the form to create the rule. Most items have a little `?` icon to help with details.

Tips for some of the fields in the form:

- Targets: select all instances in the network.
- Source IP ranges: enter `0.0.0.0/0` OR your actual IP CIDR block if you know it.
- Protocols and ports: Click "tcp", enter 9000-9400, 10600-10900 in the box.
- If your PBX is using UDP do the same for the "udp" box.